# php form disappears

Tags: php, sql, forms, authentication, registration

i have a members registration form that displays perfectly until i add the php. Once the php code is added the form completely disappears. I have tried everything but i think a fresh set of eyes is needed at this stage. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers.

```
<?php

if ( $_POST['registerbtn'] ) {
    $getuser = $_POST['user'];
    $getemail = $_POST['email'];
    $getpass = $_POST['pass'];
    $getretypepass = $_POST['retypepass'];

    if ($getuser) {
        if ($getemail) {
            if($getpass) {
                if ($getretypepass) {
                    if ($getpass === $getretypepass) {
                        if ( (strlen($getemail) >= 7) && (strstr($getemail, "@")) && (strstr($getemail, "."))) {
                            require("./connect.php");

                            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$getuser'");
                            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                            if ($numrows == 0){
                                    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$getemail'");
                                    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                                    if ($numrows == 0){

                                        $password = md5($password);
                                        $date = date("F d, Y");
                                        $code = md5(rand());

                                        mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES (
                                            '', '$getuser', '$getpassword', '$getemail', '0', '$getcode', '$getdate'
                                        )");



                                        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$getusername'");
                                        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                                        if ($numrows == 1) {

                                            $site ="http://localhost/member.php";
                                            $webmaster = "Bror Phren <bmdoublec@hotmail.com>";
                                            $headers = "From: $webmaster";
                                            $subject = "Activate your account";
                                            $message = "Thanks for registering. Click the link below to activate your account";
                                            $message .= "$site/activate.php?user=$getuser&code=$code\n";
                                            $message .= "You must activate your account t login.";

                                            if (mail($getemail, $subject, $message, $headers) ) {
                                                $errormsg = "You have been registered. You must activate your account from the activation link sent to <b>$getemail</b> ";
                                                $getuser = "";
                                                $getemail = "";
                                            }
                                            else
                                                $errormsg = "An error has occured. Your activation email was not sent";


                                        }
                                        else
                                            $errormsg = "An error has occured. Your account was not created.\n";


                            }
                            else
                                $errormsg = "There is already a user with that email";

                            }
                            else
                                $errormsg = "There is already a user with that username";

                            mysql_close();


                        }
                        else
                        $errormsg = "You must enter a valid email address to register.";

                }
                else
                $errormsg = "You must retype your password to register.";

            }
            else
            $errormsg = "You must enter password to register.";

        }
        else
            $errormsg = "You must enter email to register.";

    }
    else
        $errormsg = "You must enter username to register.";
```

}

```
$form = "<form action='./register.php' method='post'>
<table>

    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><font color='red'>$errormsg</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

    <td>Username:</td>
    <td><input type='text' name='user' value='$getuser' /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Email:</td>
    <td><input type='text' name='email' value='$getemail' /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Password:</td>
    <td><input type='password' name='pass' value='' /></td>
    </tr>

        <tr>
    <td>Retype:</td>
    <td><input type='password' name='retypepass' value='' /></td>
    </tr>

        <tr>
    <td>Retype:</td>
    <td><input type='submit' name='registerbtn' value='Register' /></td>
    </tr>

    </table>
</form>";

echo $form;

}

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Are you seeing a blank white screen when you add the PHP? If so it's probably a fatal error producing a 500 internal server error, check your error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT: As mentioned by Armon Toubman, the form will only display if relevant data has been posted to the page. You need to move the form outside of the if statement. See code below:**

```
<?php

if ( $_POST['registerbtn'] ) {
    $getuser = $_POST['user'];
    $getemail = $_POST['email'];
    $getpass = $_POST['pass'];
    $getretypepass = $_POST['retypepass'];

    if ($getuser) {
        if ($getemail) {
            if($getpass) {
                if ($getretypepass) {
                    if ($getpass === $getretypepass) {
                        if ( (strlen($getemail) >= 7) && (strstr($getemail, "@")) && (strstr($getemail, "."))) {
                            require("./connect.php");

                            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$getuser'");
                            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                            if ($numrows == 0){
                                    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$getemail'");
                                    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                                    if ($numrows == 0){

                                        $password = md5($password);
                                        $date = date("F d, Y");
                                        $code = md5(rand());

                                        mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES (
                                            '', '$getuser', '$getpassword', '$getemail', '0', '$getcode', '$getdate'
                                        )");



                                        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$getusername'");
                                        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                                        if ($numrows == 1) {

                                            $site ="http://localhost/member.php";
                                            $webmaster = "Bror Phren <bmdoublec@hotmail.com>";
                                            $headers = "From: $webmaster";
                                            $subject = "Activate your account";
                                            $message = "Thanks for registering. Click the link below to activate your account";
                                            $message .= "$site/activate.php?user=$getuser&code=$code\n";
                                            $message .= "You must activate your account t login.";

                                            if (mail($getemail, $subject, $message, $headers) ) {
                                                $errormsg = "You have been registered. You must activate your account from the activation link sent to <b>$getemail</b> ";
                                                $getuser = "";
                                                $getemail = "";
                                            }
                                            else
                                                $errormsg = "An error has occured. Your activation email was not sent";
                                        }
                                        else
                                            $errormsg = "An error has occured. Your account was not created.\n";
                            }
                            else
                                $errormsg = "There is already a user with that email";
                            }
                            else
                                $errormsg = "There is already a user with that username";
                        }
                        else
                        $errormsg = "You must enter a valid email address to register.";
                }
                else
                $errormsg = "You must retype your password to register.";
            }
            else
            $errormsg = "You must enter password to register.";
        }
        else
            $errormsg = "You must enter email to register.";

    }
    else
        $errormsg = "You must enter username to register.";
    }
    mysql_close();
}
?>
<form action='./register.php' method='post'>
<table>

    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><font color='red'><?php if(isset($errormsg){ echo $errormsg; } ?></font></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>    
      <td>Username:</td>
      <td><input type='text' name='user' value='<?php if(isset($getuser){ echo $getuser; } ?>' /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Email:</td>
      <td><input type='text' name='email' value='<?php if(isset($getemail){ echo $getemail; } ?>' /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Password:</td>
      <td><input type='password' name='pass' value='' /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Retype:</td>
      <td><input type='password' name='retypepass' value='' /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Retype:</td>
      <td><input type='submit' name='registerbtn' value='Register' /></td>
    </tr>

    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: I also moved the MySQL close statement for clarity. As commented by Madara Uchiha on your question, you should consider using prepared statements also.

Answer (score 1):

Your echo statement is inside your if ( $_POST['registerbtn'] ) {} block, meaning the form isn't displayed if it isn't submitted.

Comment: That explains it yes. Move the form outside of this if statement and use `isset` to check and see if `$errormsg`, `$getuser` and `$getemail` is set before printing them e.g. `if(isset($errormsg) { echo $errormsg;}`

Answer (score 1):

You have errors in PHP code which are preventing anything from running.

I would suggest running your code through something like PHPLint to see the errors.

Also, you may want to consider structuring your code in a way that is easier to read and maintain.

For example, you could avoid all those nested if statements and write it as:

```
if (!$getuser) {
   $errormsg = "You must enter username to register.";
}
else if (!$getemail) {
   $errormsg = "You must enter email to register.";
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use else

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['registerbtn'])) {
    $getuser = $_POST['user'];
    $getemail = $_POST['email'];
    $getpass = $_POST['pass'];
    $getretypepass = $_POST['retypepass'];

    if ($getuser) {
        if ($getemail) {
            if($getpass) {
                if ($getretypepass) {
                    if ($getpass === $getretypepass) {
                        if ( (strlen($getemail) >= 7) && (strstr($getemail, "@")) && (strstr($getemail, "."))) {
                            require("./connect.php");

                            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$getuser'");
                            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                            if ($numrows == 0){
                                    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$getemail'");
                                    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                                    if ($numrows == 0){

                                        $password = md5($password);
                                        $date = date("F d, Y");
                                        $code = md5(rand());

                                        mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES (
                                            '', '$getuser', '$getpassword', '$getemail', '0', '$getcode', '$getdate'
                                        )");



                                        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$getusername'");
                                        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                                        if ($numrows == 1) {

                                            $site ="http://localhost/member.php";
                                            $webmaster = "Bror Phren <bmdoublec@hotmail.com>";
                                            $headers = "From: $webmaster";
                                            $subject = "Activate your account";
                                            $message = "Thanks for registering. Click the link below to activate your account";
                                            $message .= "$site/activate.php?user=$getuser&code=$code\n";
                                            $message .= "You must activate your account t login.";

                                            if (mail($getemail, $subject, $message, $headers) ) {
                                                $errormsg = "You have been registered. You must activate your account from the activation link sent to <b>$getemail</b> ";
                                                $getuser = "";
                                                $getemail = "";
                                            }
                                            else
                                                $errormsg = "An error has occured. Your activation email was not sent";


                                        }
                                        else
                                            $errormsg = "An error has occured. Your account was not created.\n";


                            }
                            else
                                $errormsg = "There is already a user with that email";

                            }
                            else
                                $errormsg = "There is already a user with that username";

                            mysql_close();


                        }
                        else
                        $errormsg = "You must enter a valid email address to register.";

                }
                else
                $errormsg = "You must retype your password to register.";

            }
            else
              $errormsg = "You must enter password to register.";

        }
        else
            $errormsg = "You must enter email to register.";
    }
    else
        $errormsg = "You must enter username to register.";
}
}
```

here

```
else{ 
$form = "<form action='./register.php' method='post'>
<table>

    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><font color='red'>$errormsg</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

    <td>Username:</td>
    <td><input type='text' name='user' value='$getuser' /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Email:</td>
    <td><input type='text' name='email' value='$getemail' /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Password:</td>
    <td><input type='password' name='pass' value='' /></td>
    </tr>

        <tr>
    <td>Retype:</td>
    <td><input type='password' name='retypepass' value='' /></td>
    </tr>

        <tr>
    <td>Retype:</td>
    <td><input type='submit' name='registerbtn' value='Register' /></td>
    </tr>

    </table>
</form>";

echo $form;

}

?>
```

Comment: Its okay man. if you thought my answer solves the probs means then accept the answer..